# '--no-self-contained' has no effect

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET 6 project that I need to build in a azure devops build pipeline for.

My current azure-pipelines file looksl ike this:

```
trigger:
- release/*
pool:
  name: Test

variables:
  solution: 'acoolproject.sln'
  acoolprojectweb: 'acoolproject.web\acoolproject.web.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.7.0'
- task: gitversion/execute@0
  inputs:
    updateAssemblyInfo: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: $(solution)
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: $(acoolprojectweb)
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -c $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: variabledehydration@0
  inputs:
    prefixes: 'GITVERSION,BUILD'
    outpath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

And this would build a project for me with a "runtimes" folder in it, that would take up around 170-180 MB, making the project way larger than it actually was.

I then studied up a bit on it, and figured I should try to make the project not self contained, and build only for a windows runtime, which is what I need.

So I changed my publish task to look like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: $(acoolprojectweb)
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -c $(buildConfiguration)  --self-contained false'
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

With this flag, the "runtimes" folder is still present, and the project takes up exactly as much space a before.
Why does making the project not self contained have no effect on anything?

**EDIT**

I also tried also targeting the specific runtime that I need:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
  command: 'publish'
  publishWebProjects: false
  projects: $(acoolprojectweb)
  arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -c $(buildConfiguration) -r win10-x86 --self-contained false'
  zipAfterPublish: false

This cuts down the size by a bit, but now it has binaries that are just laying in the root of the project that is taking up space, especially these three:

```
-a----        21-05-2023     10:45       28327824 icudt68.dll
-a----        21-05-2023     10:45        2759032 icuin68.dll
-a----        21-05-2023     10:45        1864080 icuuc68.dll
```

When I make it self contained, why does it have these bulky dll's?